# WinDbg TTD: No trace files were identified from this record session

Tags: windbg

Trying to record execution of Hello World with WinDbg from store.

WinDbg settings:

```
Executable path: C:\Users\...\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\TestApplication\Debug\TestApplication.exe

Output directory: c:\Users\...\Documents\
```

Code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Error:

> TTD: No trace files were identified from this record session
>
> The debugging session could not be started: Path cannot be null.
> Parameter name: path

Why it's does not work? What I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

Occasionally TTD recording has trouble creating TTD files to paths with spaces. Recommend entering or pointing Output Directory to save TTD files to a path with no spaces.

Comment: That's true. Non-ASCII characters also cause similar error.